# How to include multiple model in rails lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my /lib i have this class below:

```
module Application
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessor :id

     def artilce_content
        post.articles.content
     end

     private
        def post
           Post.find(id)
        end
  end
end
```

But the problem is `article` is undefined.

`NoMethodError: undefined method ziptag_type' for #<Application::Api::V2::Ziptag:0x00000008edc120>`

The question is, how can I use or include multiple models in /lib? I tried adding `class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end` above `module`

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base; end

module Application
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base; end
        :
        :
        :
  end
end
```

but is doesn't worked.

Comment: That is different with my question. That is for including module, not Model. I want to use `Article` model inside the class `Post`.

Comment: @bo-oz, I didn't do it via model because I have a multiple api versions and it's better to version via `/lib` for safety of my api versions.. web version will give me a bunch of thankful because of this it won't affect anything on any web and api versions.. And... I have been solved it below....

Comment: Why is this in the `/lib` directory?

Comment: Hi @Rich Peck, I just put it in a /lib directory to avoid a serious distruction with other methods in models. This is a existing and huge code app. I decided to put in in lib so if I have some fix in a method that other version needed, it wont affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way here is to use require.

```
require 'your_model'
```

In your case, it should be:

```
require 'article'

module Application
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :id

    def artilce_content
      post.articles.content
    end

    private
      def post
        Post.find(id)
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. My answer previously didn't work in some cases in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer. It should be:

`class Article < ActiveRecord::Base; attr_accessor :column1, :other_column end`

Not:

`class Article < ActiveRecord::Base; end`

Now, it's working fine on me.